# How can I create a border around a cylinder mesh that protrudes forwards

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a cylinder mesh and I want to create a border around it that protrudes forwards. Would anyone be able to explain how I could do this? I know how to create edge loops, but im still finding this a bit difficult.

Here is a references example:

[image]

As you can see in the image there is a black border around the yellow mesh and it protrudes slightly forward. I want to create this protrusion.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: so I guess you need to play with some insets and extrusions? The black surfaces could also be different meshes, as it would be the case in reality

Answer (score 1):

How is the face of the cylinder filled? If it's filled with a triangle fan (single central vertex) then you won't be able to add an edge loop. One way to add one is to duplicate the outer circle of vertices and build a ring off of that by extruding it inwards to make it solid then extrude those faces outward to give it depth.